# How to convert time from .net epoch to time in Unix epoch with Ruby?

Tags: c#, .net, ruby, unix-timestamp

I have an input timestamp from `C#` (`.NET` epoch: `00:00:00 (midnight), January 1, 0001`) and I want to output it in `Ruby` world (`Unix` epoch: `00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970`).

The input timestamp is given in `UTC`, and derived from .NET's [DateTime(Int64)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx), which is "*a date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar.*"

The input timestamp: `634891434586852680`

Output should be 2012-NOV-21 a bit after 5pm PST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input =                         634891434586852680
UNIX_EPOCH_IN_100NS_INTERVALS = 621355968000000000

Time.at((input-UNIX_EPOCH_IN_100NS_INTERVALS)*1e-7).utc.getlocal
 => 2012-11-21 17:10:58 -0800
```

In Ruby, [Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html) *is stored internally as the number of seconds with fraction since the Epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC.* Therefore we must convert from `100-nanosecond intervals` to `seconds`.

The conversion factor of `1e-7` is `1e2/1e9` which is `100/1000000000` which can be explained as:

```
X intervals * 100ns/interval * 1s/1000000000ns
```

The `intervals` cancel themselves out, as do the `nanoseconds`, and we are left with `seconds`; and `100/1000000000 seconds` is `1e2/1e9 seconds` which is `1e-7 seconds`.